# Как из Pydantic все собранные ошибки корректно передать в json файл

Tags: python, pydantic

Итак у меня есть модель для валидации:

```
class ElementModel(BaseModel):
    id: str
    type: str
    atr1: Optional[float]
    atr2: Optional[float]
    atr3: Optional[float]
    atr4: Optional[float]
    atr5: Optional[float]

    @root_validator
    def check_req_attrs(cls, values):
        el_type = values.get('type')
        el_attrs = set(key for key in values.keys() if values[key] != None)
        if el_type == 'value1':
            req_attrs = {'atr1', 'atr2'}
            req_attrs.difference_update(el_attrs)
            if req_attrs:
                raise ValueError(f"{req_attrs} are missing")
        return values

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    uniqe_uuid: str
    elements: List[ElementModel]
```

Все работает нормально. Но есть два вопроса:

1. Мне нужно ошибки выявленные при валидации передать в формате json файла.
   Сейчас я делаю так:

```
try:
    my_model = MyModel(uniqe_uuid = 'uniqe_uuid', elements=elements_list)
except ValueError as e:
    errors_dict = json.loads(e.json())
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'report.json'), 'w') as file:
        json.dump(errors_dict, file, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
```

и меня напрягает что приходится переводить объект ValueError сначала в строку, потом в словарь, а потом уже в json. Есть более правильный способ внутри pydantic?

2. При работе `@root_validator` выявленная ошибка после перевода в json формат отображается так:

```
{
    "loc": [
      "elements",
      0,
      "__root__"
    ],
    "msg": "{'atr1'} parameters are missing",
    "type": "value_error"
  }
```

А мне нужно чтобы отсутствующие обязательные поля прописывались вместо "`__root__`". Как например они прописываются если не проходит валидация внутри класса:

```
{
    "loc": [
      "elements",
      2,
      "id"
    ],
    "msg": "field required",
    "type": "value_error.missing"
  }
```

Здесь пишется именно отсутствующее поле "id"

Заранее благодарен!)

Comment: На первую часть: просто открываете файл и пишете в него через `file.write(e.json())` (не нужен предварительный json.loads и запись в файл через json.dump)

Comment: По второй части, можно реализовать отдельные классы для разных значений поля type. В доках по pydantic такое называется [Discriminated Unions (a.k.a. Tagged Unions)](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#discriminated-unions-aka-tagged-unions). При валидации указывает распознанный класс и отсутствующие для этого класса требуемые поля. Примерная реализация: https://pastebin.com/8cYkfukS (тестировалось на Pydantic 1.9.0, на более старых версиях может глючить валидация). Если такой вариант подойдет, оформлю ответом.

Comment: Также добавил ответ под прошлым вопросом с реализацией через Discriminated Unions: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1373102/1365

Comment: @insolor Спасибо за комментарий. Да пожалуйста оформите как ответ, решение меня устраивает. Еще раз спасибо.