Как в Pydantic использовать fild_validator, если поле описано в другом классе?
Если Test.version == "2.1" нужно выполнить проверку поля Offer.new.
Упрощенный json (реальный намного больше, поэтому и разбит на классы):
{
    "data":
    {
        "id": 11,
        "offer":
        [
            {
                "offer_id": 8,
                "new": "qwerty"
            }
        ],
        "version": "2.1"
    }
}

Как я пробовал:
from enum import StrEnum
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator

class Versions(StrEnum):
    v2_0 = '2.0'
    v2_1 = '2.1'

class Offer(BaseModel):
    offer_id: int

    @field_validator('version')
    def check_version(cls, values):
        if values == '2.1':
            new: str

class Data(BaseModel):
    id: int
    offer: List[Offer]

class Test(BaseModel):
    data: Data
    version: Versions

Еще пробовал так:
if Test.values == '2.1':

Получаю ошибку:
pydantic.errors.PydanticUserError: Decorators defined with incorrect
fields: schemas.test.Offer:45545536.check_version
(use check_fields=False if you're inheriting from the model and intended this)


Что именно вы хотите проверить (валидировать)? Какой результат должен получиться в итоге?

@insolor в версии Х добавили новое обязательное поле, по этому если версия == Х нужно проверить, что данное поле соответствует заданному типу. Если версия отличается то данной - поля не будет и проверять нечего.

Сделайте вообще отдельные версии классов для разных версий. Нужный вариант выбирайте через discriminated unions: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/unions/#discriminated-unions-with-str-discriminators, тут пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1373102/1365. Если через валидаторы делать, то придется валидировать в том классе, где есть поле version.
